# What is different between asp.net and c#.net webform? Is that same or different?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to verify that asp.net and c#.net web forms are different or same. I am looking to be a c#.net developer in WinForm And WebForm too. Also What do get learn or share some interesting website from which I can able to learn the c#.net.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as "C#.NET web forms". In fact, there's no such thing as "C#.NET".

It's important that you understand the difference between:

- C# (a language)
- The CLR (a virtual machine that C# code *typically* runs on)
- Framework libraries (including ASP.NET)
- The overall platform ".NET" which includes framework libraries, the CLR and a C# compiler.

As for the best resource to learn C# - I suggest you get hold of a good beginner's book. The *second* edition of [Head-First C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449380344) is good if you like that style, or [Essential C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321694694) and [C# 4 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596800959) are both good if you're happy with more traditional books. Of course, there are plenty of other books out there.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of a C# book myself, but I don't think it would be appropriate for you at this point; it's not a beginner's book.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing a valuable information. Which software Did I need to get it to learn on c# and .net libraries?

Comment: Start with a web browser and READ THE DOCUMENTATION at Microsoft's MSDN site. It is all there, you know.

Comment: @mitultechs - Get [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express). If you want to do web development, get the Web Developer edition. If you want non web development in C# get the C# edition.

Comment: @Oded that was really helpful for me. However I am just clarifying. I am using Visual Studio 2008. I dont know how to start it. What to learn or what to do in practical way?

Comment: @mitultechs - Start with one of the books that Jon recommended. I don't even know what "I don't know how to start it" means - you start it like you do all other installed software.

Answer (score 3):

[ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/) is a framework (or really a framework family) for building web applications. The framework contains support for different approaches for building applications, such as:

- [ASP.NET Webforms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms)
- [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)
- [ASP.NET Webpages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages)

C# is a language you can use with the framework.